# First ajax call status 0 "error" but second ajax call status 4 "200"

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I ran into a serious problem. Firstly:

**Ajax call is sent by cordova app on an Android device to a Windows Server (IIS, PHP) protected by base authentication and ssl.**

Since we updated the GlobalSign nv-sa certificate last time (some days ago) the ajax call gets status 0 at the first try after 30 seconds, but status 4 and "200" on the second try (Tapping first time after 30 seconds status 0 -> tapping second time status 4 immediately). The only difference to the old certificate is: the new one is not anymore sha1 but sha256 fingerprint...

From the second tap on, every tap results in 4 "200" without any problems but first one always gets 0 "error".

Code:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          async: asyncVar, // for Android: false - for iOS: true

          username: db.getItem("user"),
          password: db.getItem("pass"),
          xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },

          data: { forename: db.getItem("forename"), surname: db.getItem("surname"), uuid: db.getItem("uuid"), mail: db.getItem("mail"), phone: db.getItem("phone") },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data, status, object){
            var body = object.responseText;
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(body);

            alert('test1: '+status + ' | ' + object.status + ' | ' + object.readyState + ' | ' + object.statusText + ' | ' + data);

            //alert("test: "+obj.auth);

            if(obj.auth == '1')
            {
                db.setItem("auth","1");
            }
            else
            {
                db.setItem("auth","0");
            }
        },
        error: function(object, status, errorThrown){
            db.setItem("auth","0");
            alert('test2: '+status + ' | ' + object.status + ' | ' + object.readyState + ' | ' + object.statusText + ' | ' + errorThrown);
        }
}).always(function(object, status, errorThrown){
        if(db.getItem("auth") == "1")
        {
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change","#pageLocations");
        }
        else
        {
            db.setItem("auth","0");
        }
        alert('test3: '+status + ' | ' + object.status + ' | ' + object.readyState + ' | ' + object.statusText + ' | ' + errorThrown);
});
```

**Exact result of code:**

First tap:

```
test2: error | 0 | 0 | error |
test3: error | 0 | 0 | error |
```

Second, third, etc... tap:

```
test1: success | 200 | 4 | OK | [object Object]
test3: success | undefined | undefined | undefined | [object Object]
```

Do you have any idea what could be the reason for this or am I doing anything wrong?

Thnx. in advance for your help.

Comment: Does nobody have any idea or did I explain the problem not good enough...?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it to work now. The solution was simple:

The intermediate certificate of GlobalSign was missing, so we installed it on the server, restarted it and it worked...

There was no problem with the source code! Just the certificate and the intermediate certificate had to be installed.